# How to disable INFO logging from a third party module in Python

Tags: python, suppress-warnings

I'm querying a Serf cluster using Python but I would like to suppress the `INFO` data that comes from Serf. I've tried to override it so that it will only print `WARNING` messages but it refuses to honor it.

## Output:

```
01-04 14:57 root         INFO     Connecting to cluster
01-04 14:57 serf-rpc-client INFO     will connect to [('myhost.localdomain.local', 7373, {})]
01-04 14:57 serf-rpc-client INFO     trying to connect to myhost.localdomain.local:7373
01-04 14:57 serf-rpc-client INFO     connected to myhost.localdomain.local:7373
01-04 14:57 serf-rpc-client INFO     trying to request command: <RequestHandshake: handshake, 0, {'Version': 1}>
01-04 14:57 serf-rpc-client INFO     trying to request command: <RequestAuth: auth, 1, {'AuthKey': 'thundercats'}>
01-04 14:57 serf-rpc-client INFO     trying to request command: <RequestMembers: members, 2, {'Status': 'failed'}>
01-04 14:57 serf-rpc-client INFO     successfully handshaked
01-04 14:57 serf-rpc-client INFO     successfully authed
01-04 14:57 root         INFO     myhost123.localdomain.local has left the cluster
```

## Logging Code

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                filename='/var/log/ocd_watcher.log',
                filemode='w')

serf_logger = logging.getLogger('serf')
serf_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
console_handler.setFormatter(default_formatter)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(console_handler)
logger.addHandler(serf_logger)
```

Comment: So you want to get `INFO` messages from other things but *not* `serf`?

Comment: yeah, i actually figured it out a few minutes later while waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logger name is `serf-rpc-client` so this should work

```
serf_logger = logging.getLogger('serf-rpc-client')
serf_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: Yeah I figured it out afterwars by looking at the source - duh! Is there a quicker way to know this?

Comment: Reading the log - `01-04 14:57 serf-rpc-client INFO   ` - the first is date, then the logger name and finally the level. If the question helps,

Comment: Ah ok i did notice that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I will, it wont let me. I have to wait. :-)